# decrytption in ios 7 not working using aes

Tags: objective-c, encryption, ios7

In My App, i'm getting data from xml, where it is encrypted, and i need to decrypt the received nsstring,

```
 UserName = @"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==";
```

I Need to decrypt this nsstring into regular format, i searched and find aes , but it doesn't make any changes,

```
  NSString* msg = [FBEncryptorAES decryptBase64String:UserName
                                          keyString:@"01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];

if (msg)
{
    UserName = msg;

    NSLog(@"decrypted: %@", msg);
} else
{
    UserName = @"(failed to decrypt)";
}
```

How can i decrypt the above nsstring, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to know the process that was used to encrypt the string. The string looks like base 64 so you would probably need to decode it (result is "@HώO=Bn" assuming UTF-8). I assume your key is a placeholder though (since it seems too large for an AES key) so I wasn't able to see if that decrypts to a meaningful value

Answer (score 0):

The string is not only AES encrypted, it is Base64 encoded. The trailing "==" is typical of base64 padding. Also AES encryption produces data bytes, not ASCII characters and the output is a multiple of the block size. It is common to Base64 encode the result of encryption so it is ASCII and can be included in XML.

For iOS 7 there are several Base64 API methods for NSData. Probably what you want is:

```
- (id)initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)base64String options:(NSDataBase64DecodingOptions)options
```

Example:

```
NSString *userName = @"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:userName options:0];
NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
```

NSLog output:
data: <4048db1e fccf8e4f 98b8b0d5 3d426e10>

The data probably is AES encrypted, it is a multiple of block length, and if so you will need the key and also information on padding, mode and possibly iv.

Note that the `FBEncryptorAES` class method `encryptedBase64String` does accept Base64 input but the decryption key string is suspect and the encryption may not match this decryption method due to method and possible iv. So the `FBEncryptorAES` class may not be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as i tried your suggesstions but the resulting nsdata cannot be converted to original form, as i tried "NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding", it results the same string type of string "QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==", or when i use "NSUTF8StringEncoding", it returns (null).How to get the original string which is in the server.

Comment: There are two steps: 1-decode the Base64 string to data. 2-decrypt the data with AES. Step 2 is the catch because you need to know the key, padding, mode and iv. There may be no padding (unlikely). The mode is probably CBC which would require an iv or ECB which would not require an iv. You need to know the things. Only the key is secret. Some software combines all these things and you would need to read the docs to find them out. Some software such as php do not pad properly making things more difficult. I suggest you get this information and provide an example with all of this information.

Comment: NSString *userName = @"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==";
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:userName options:0];
    NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
    

    NSString *key = @"01234567890123456789012345678901";
    NSData *plaintext = [data AES256DecryptWithKey:key];
    NSLog(@"plaintext: %@", plaintext);

Comment: i tried the above coding , as you mentioned in step 1, but still it goes empty

Comment: You will have to find out exactly how the server encodes/encrypts the data if you need to make this work.

Comment: Iam using the tutorial for encryption from the following link, http://www.obviex.com/samples/encryptionwithsalt.aspx#. How to generate ios codes based on this passpharse and IV.I totally got struck in it, please give me suggesstions

Comment: I looked at the tutorial, seems good but very involved. If you want to learn more about security get some books. One reference used by many cryptographers is "The Handbook Of Applied Cryptography", it is available for free download from [The CRCPress](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/). Most books by Bruce Schneier.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will try your suggesstions and reply you