# Decoding and Encoding in Xcode

Tags: ios, nsstring, base64, decode

Iam new to Ios,. in my App,i receive data from server,and i have to decode the receving data, i tried the following sample code,

```
 NSData * dt = [Base64 decode:@"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="];
 NSString * actualString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dt 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",actualString);
```

This returns value "Hello World",

But if i try with the data , which i got from the server through xml,

```
 NSData * dt = [Base64 decode:@"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA=="];
 NSString * actualString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dt 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@",actualString);
```

it returns (null), and cannot able to decode, is there the problem in '+' symbol, whether i have to encode data without '+' symbol in the server side, if not necessary means , what is the right way to achieve it, Please suggesst me.Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20762134/451475)

Answer (score 1):

As you code : `NSData * dt = [Base64 decode:@"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA=="];`

The `actualString` is nil because your `dt` data does not represent valid data for encoding.

I think the key issues is your `@"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA=="` is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your response , i will try to change the format

Comment: @Guo This is a similar question asked a few days ago. In that question according to the OP there is AES encryption involved. When the @"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==" string is Base64 decoded to data it produces data that is a multiple of the AES block size. See [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20762134/451475)

Comment: @Zaph ,Oh~~~I am sorry that I just found this is a duplicated question. Yes , I see the string is ended with "==",It may be encrypted by AES128(maybe) , so the OP should first decrypted the string (@"QEjbHvzPjk+YuLDVPUJuEA==") with AES Key, and then decode with base64.